# Get row ID when user double clicks the row in ALV report

Tags: abap, alv

I have a scenario which displays a list of purchase documents as ALV (function module `REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY`). By clicking on a purchase doc no, its specific details (e.g. `NETPR`) should show in a pop up. How should I do it?

```
  FORM USER_COMMAND USING R_UCOMM LIKE SY-UCOMM
        RS_SELFIELD TYPE SLIS_SELFIELD.
    CASE r_ucomm.
      WHEN '&IC1'.

        READ TABLE ITAB INTO WA WITH KEY EBELN = WA-EBELN.
        PERFORM popup_display.

    ENDCASE.
  ENDFORM.                    "user_command
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the subroutine in structure `RS_SELFIELD` is what you need:

field `TABINDEX` contains the line, which was double clicked (`you can READ TABLE the internal table which holds the data with INDEX rs_selfield-tabindex`) and field `FIELDNAME` contains the field, which was clicked (`if that is relevant in your case`).

Also check the documentation of the function module `SE37 => Function Module Documentation`, lots of useful information there `see I_CALLBACK_USER_PROGRAM`